# Keyword proximity matching - options?

Tags: c#-4.0, lucene.net, text-parsing

I have a case where I have an array of keywords.  I want to find their matches within a given string and return x number of words before and after each.

I could write a looping engine that goes through an array of each, returning a given index, and performing concatenated sub-strings based on those loops, but this seems a bit lengthy.

I've heard of Lucene, but not sure if implementing an entire framework to do this is worth it.  Also, if possible, how can I accomplish with Lucene?

Thanks.

Comment: I did something similar and sought to use Lucene.net.  Lucene was not built with an efficient way of doing what you want, however, it does have some good tokenizers that might be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps regular expressions would help...
This builds a list of matching strings (up to 3 words before) keyword (up to 3 words after)

Edit: I missed a couple 0s and some @s.  Try again.

```
private static void GetMatches (string s)
{
   string[] keywords = {"if", "while", "do"};
   int x = 3; // words before and after
   string ex =
      @"(\w+\W+){0," + x + @"}\b(" + string.Join("|", keywords) + @")\b\W+(\w+\W+){0," + x + @"}";
   Regex regex = new Regex(ex);
   List<string> matches = new List<string>();
   foreach (Match match in regex.Matches (s))
   {
      matches.Add(match.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  It only seems to match on "while" and only ever returns "while"... no surrounding words.  If it worked, I this could be useful in what I'm currently trying out.  I've now got a sorted array of all the indices for all keywords within a given string.

Comment: Try again if you like... I missed a few characters.

Comment: Ah, lovely.  way simpler than the approach I was taking.  Thanks!